# style="display:none" is not working. Jquery toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, display

I am trying to filter a div, and it is giving `style="sidplay:none"` to all elements which are not in search result and it is working fine, but the attribute is not hiding the element!

[Image here (direct image not available for me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ThBB.png)

my code

```js
WikiOption.Elements.searchInput.on("input", (thisx)=> {
    
    var val = $(thisx.target).val();
    $(".toc-wrap h3").each(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(val));
    });
});
```

Comment: because you have some css attribute with more priority like (!important). for example : display: block!important; your problem not related jquery code. it is css

Comment: What is `WikiOption.Elements.searchInput` ? Also, there's nothing in the provided code that changes `styles`.

Comment: Consider it as an element

Answer (score 0):

`.toggle()` isn't the right method to use in your case. If the next input event fires and a `<h3>` matches again, then it would change back to it's former state. Use `if/else` statements and `.show()` and `.hide()` methods.

Also, `input` event doesn't trigger if you <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and leave the `<input>` empty, so a `keyup` event handler is added.

```js
$('.search').on('input', function(e) {
  const txt = $(e.target).val().toLowerCase();
  $('.toc-wrap h3').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(txt)) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});

$('.search').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 8 && $(this).val() === '') {
    $('.toc-wrap h3').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
h3 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<input class='search' type='search'>
<article class='toc-wrap'>
  <h3>ABCDEFGHIJ</h3>
  <h3>klmnopqrst</h3>
  <h3>uvwxyz</h3>
  <h3>aAbBcC</h3>
</article>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```